# How can I save my data on phone orientation?

Tags: android, android-fragments, transactions, fragment, onsaveinstancestate

I'm having difficulties with making my app persistent. When I rotate my phone the data on the screen doesnt change. But after I click on a button to retrieve a new fragment I get an error saying "Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState". I have googled and seen similiar problems but I still dont know how to approach and solve this.

I have an activity class, a controller class and two fragment classes. 
The activity class has a navigationviewer with 2 buttons that triggers a fragmenttransaction. That is, on each button click it will replace the current fragment with the one set in the button listener. My controller class initalizes the system and the fragments are just the UI.

**My activity class**:

```
public class LoggedInActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final String TAG = "LoggedInActivity: ";
    private Controller controller;
    private TextView navName;
    private NavigationView navigationView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.v(TAG, "onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_logged_in);
        if(savedInstanceState == null) {
            Log.v(TAG, "savedInstanceState == null");
            initComponents();
            setNavName();
            initListener();
            initializeSystem();
        } else {
            Log.v(TAG, "savedInstanceState != null");
            initComponents();
            setNavName();
            initListener();
            this.controller = (Controller)savedInstanceState.getSerializable("controller");
        }
    }


    private void initComponents() {
        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
        View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        navName = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name_surname);

    }

    private void initListener() {
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new MyNavigationItemListener());
    }

    private void initializeSystem() {
        Log.v(TAG, "new controller");
        controller = new Controller(this, null);
    }

    public void setFragment(Fragment fragment) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container_logged_in, fragment).commit();
    }



    private class MyNavigationItemListener implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch(item.getItemId()) {

                case R.id.drawer_summary:
                    controller.setFragmentSummary();
                    break;

                case R.id.drawer_income:
                    controller.setFragmentIncome();
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putSerializable("controller", controller);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        Log.v(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState, saving the controller");
    }

}
```

**My controller class**:

```
public class Controller implements Serializable {
    private final String TAG = "Controller: ";

    /********************** Fragments ***********************/
    private Fragment_Income fragment_income;
    private Fragment_Summary fragment_summary;
    /********************************************************/

    /********************** Activities **********************/
    private LoggedInActivity logged_in_activity;
    /********************************************************/


    public Controller(LoggedInActivity logged_in_activity) {
        this.logged_in_activity = logged_in_activity;
        initLoggedInFragments();
        setFragmentSummary();

        }
    }



    /* Initializes fragments that are connected to LoggedInActivity */
    private void initLoggedInFragments() {
        fragment_income = new Fragment_Income();
        fragment_income.setController(this);
        fragment_summary = new Fragment_Summary();
        fragment_summary.setController(this);
    }



    /* use to replace current fragment with the given one */
    private void replaceFragmentWith(Fragment fragment) {
        logged_in_activity.setFragment(fragment);
    }



    /***********************************************************
     *          METHODS REGARDING FRAGMENT INCOME              *
     **********************************************************/

    public void setFragmentIncome() {
        replaceFragmentWith(fragment_income);
    }


    /* Summary fragment is started at first */
    public void setFragmentSummary() {
        replaceFragmentWith(fragment_summary);
    }

}
```

**Fragment_Income**:

```
public class Fragment_Income extends Fragment implements Serializable{
    private final String TAG = "Fragment_Income: ";
    private Controller controller;
    private FloatingActionButton fab_income;
    private ListView lv_income;
    private ArrayList<LvData> incomeData;
    private LvAdapterIncome lvAdapterIncome;

    public Fragment_Income() {

    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.v(TAG, "onCreateView");
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_income, container, false); // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        if(savedInstanceState != null) {
            this.controller = (Controller) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("controller");
        }
        initComponents(view);
        initListener();
        setupListView();
        return view;
    }

    private void initComponents(View view) {
        fab_income = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fab_income);
        lv_income = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lv_income);
    }


    private void initListener() {
        ButtonListener buttonListener = new ButtonListener();
        fab_income.setOnClickListener(buttonListener);
    }

    private void setupListView() {
        if (incomeData == null) { // checks if incomeData have been initalized before, if so do not change array to defualt
            incomeData = new ArrayList<>();
            lvAdapterIncome = new LvAdapterIncome(getContext(), incomeData);
        }
        lv_income.setAdapter(lvAdapterIncome);

    }


    public void setController(Controller controller) {
        this.controller = controller;
    }


    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        Log.v(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState, saving the controller");
        outState.putSerializable("controller", this.controller);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

}
```

**Fragment_Summary**:

```
public class Fragment_Summary extends Fragment implements Serializable {
    private static final String TAG = "Fragment_Summary: ";
    private Controller controller;
    private TextView tv_user;
    private TextView tv_total_revenue;
    private TextView tv_total_expenditure;
    private TextView tv_balance;
    private float totalRevenue;
    private float totalExpenditure;
    private float balance;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_summary, container, false);// Inflate the layout for this fragment
        initComponents(view);
        setUserName();
        if(savedInstanceState == null) {
            //DO SOMETHING
        }
        return view;
    }

    private void addData() {
        totalRevenue = controller.getTotalRevenue();
        totalExpenditure = controller.getTotalExpenditure();
        balance = totalRevenue - totalExpenditure;

        tv_total_revenue.setText(String.valueOf(totalRevenue));
        tv_total_expenditure.setText(String.valueOf(totalExpenditure));
        tv_balance.setText(String.valueOf(balance));
    }

    private void initComponents(View view) {
        tv_user = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_user);
        tv_total_revenue = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_revenue);
        tv_total_expenditure = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_sum_exp);
        tv_balance = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_balance);
    }


    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putString("revenue", String.valueOf(balance));
        outState.putString("totalExpenditure", String.valueOf(balance));
        outState.putString("balance", String.valueOf(balance));
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }


    public void setController(Controller controller) {
        this.controller = controller;
    }

}
```

**I have removed all the header files and some methods from my classes becuase I tought they were not relevant for this problem.**

**Here is the error log**:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1434)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1452)
    at android.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:708)
    at android.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:672)
    at com.example.user.my_app.LoggedInActivity.setFragment(LoggedInActivity.java:85)
    at com.example.user.my_app.Controller.replaceFragmentWith(Controller.java:89)
    at com.example.user.my_app.Controller.setFragmentIncome(Controller.java:99)
    at com.example.user.my_app.LoggedInActivity$MyNavigationItemListener.onNavigationItemSelected(LoggedInActivity.java:127)
    at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView$1.onMenuItemSelected(NavigationView.java:156)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:822)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:156)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:969)
    at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$1.onClick(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:342)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: Try using `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()` since you're using `AppCompatActivity`

Comment: Didnt help, thank you for the answer though. What I find odd is that when i change commit() to commitAllowingStateLoss(), the code is giving me the following error "IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed". But how can it be destroyed if it has been created in the onCreate method?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an activity state loss. See this excellent article by Alex Lockwood entitled ["Fragment Transactions & Activity State Loss"](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html). I refer to it time and again.

To quote the intro to the posting:

> The following stack trace and exception message has plagued StackOverflow ever since Honeycomb’s initial release:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1341)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1352)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:595)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:574)
```

> This post will explain why and when this exception is thrown, and will conclude with several suggestions that will help ensure it never crashes your application again.